# SQL Why is my SELECT selecting duplicate rows?

Tags: sql

This is a sub query:

```
SELECT t1.element_mark, t1.element_length, t1.element_width, t1.element_height, t1.product, t1.mass FROM IMP_ELEMENT as t1 WHERE TRIM(t1.project) = '99999';
```

This is the result:
[image]

This is my second sub query:

```
SELECT t2.element_id, t2.building, t2.floor_id, t2.deleted, t2.ELEMENT_MARK
FROM IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY as t2
WHERE TRIM(t2.project) = '99999' AND TRIM(t2.building) = '1' AND TRIM(CAST(t2.floor_id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = '1' AND t2.deleted = 0
ORDER BY t2.ELEMENT_MARK;
```

This is the result:
[image]

Now i'd like to combine them:

```
SELECT t1.element_mark, t1.element_length, t1.element_width, t1.element_height, t1.product, t1.mass, t2.element_id, t2.building, t2.floor_id, t2.deleted
FROM IMP_ELEMENT as t1
LEFT JOIN IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY as t2 ON t1.element_mark = t2.element_mark
WHERE TRIM(t2.project) = '99999' AND TRIM(t2.building) = '1' AND TRIM(CAST(t2.floor_id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = '1' AND t2.deleted = 0
ORDER BY t2.element_id;
```

And this is the result:
[image]

So what do i want?
I want only one result per "element_id".
I first want to SELECT"element_id" and then i want to find a match in the second table. To find a match i will use "element_mark". What is wrong in my query? why do i get multiple element_id?

Comment: that's because you have multiple entries corresponding to each element_mark in t1

Comment: @mck In t1 element_mark is unique. in t2 element_id is unique. So if i SELECT element_id from t2. and use that row t2.element_mark to find t1.element_mark and then thats row data. How should that query look like?

Comment: You've forgotten to apply the first query's `WHERE` clause in the combined query. That explains why you're seeing `mass` values that don't appear in query result 1, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by one of the comments, you probably have missed the `WHERE` clause in the first table. Try this query instead:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.element_mark, t1.element_length, t1.element_width, t1.element_height, t1.product, t1.mass, t2.element_id, t2.building, t2.floor_id, t2.deleted
FROM
    IMP_ELEMENT as t1
LEFT JOIN
    IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY as t2
ON
    t1.element_mark = t2.element_mark
WHERE
    TRIM(t2.project) = '99999' AND
    TRIM(t2.building) = '1' AND
    TRIM(CAST(t2.floor_id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = '1' AND
    t2.deleted = 0 AND
    TRIM(t1.project) = '99999'
ORDER BY t2.element_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

When joining two tables, in your case with a left join, if there are multiple matches on the join condition, multiple rows will be in the result set. You are joining based on element_mark- so for the first record of the first query- 3 rows will be returned in your result. What I would suggest is put the second table at the left part of the query or do a `RIGHT JOIN`. This way, because `element_mark` looks unique in the first table, you will get one record per `element_id`.

Comment: I did this with no difrent: SELECT t1.element_mark, t1.element_length, t1.element_width, t1.element_height, t1.product, t1.mass, t2.element_id, t2.building, t2.floor_id, t2.deleted
FROM IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY as t2
LEFT JOIN  IMP_ELEMENT as t1 ON t2.element_mark = t1.element_mark
WHERE TRIM(t2.project) = '99999' AND TRIM(t2.building) = '1' AND TRIM(CAST(t2.floor_id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = '1' AND t2.deleted = 0
ORDER BY t2.element_id;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all elements and get matching information -- if any -- from the second table, then you want the `LEFT JOIN`.  However, *all* conditions on the second table need to be in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t1.element_mark, t1.element_length, t1.element_width, t1.element_height, t1.product, t1.mass,
       t2.element_id, t2.building, t2.floor_id, t2.deleted
FROM IMP_ELEMENT t1 LEFT JOIN 
     IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY t2 
     ON t1.element_mark = t2.element_mark AND
        TRIM(t2.project) = '99999' AND
        TRIM(t2.building) = '1' AND 
        TRIM(CAST(t2.floor_id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = '1' AND
        t2.deleted = 0
ORDER BY t2.element_id;
```

There is no `WHERE` clause because all the filters are on the second table.